# Laravel generate different urls with parameter

Tags: laravel, url, routes

I have multiple html elements and everyone should refer to another the same route but with a dynamic seccond parameter

like `Route::get('categorie/{categorie}', 'Group\GroupController@index');`

There are three different html elements.

Everyone have his own

```
<a href="{{ route('categorie/.' + 'anything') }}">
<a href="{{ route('categorie/.' + 'gaming') }}">
<a href="{{ route('categorie/.' + 'unicorn') }}">
```

Now I don't get it to work.. I also want to get the seccond parameter in my controller

```
public function index(Request $request) {
        return $request['categorie'];
}
```

Can someone tell me how I can do this?

I've tried something like that :

```
<a href="{{ url / route ('categorie', 'anything', ['categorie' => 'allgemein']) }}">  ( for each href )
```

But this only let my site crash

Does someone knows a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller method to

```
public function index(Request $request, $categorie) {
    return $categorie;
}
```